# Is Armor granted by spells reduced if you have already hit the softcap?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I am only Level 7 with my Orc Dragonknight, but I have already hit the soft cap for armor:

[image: Screenshot of character attributes]

Now I can morph an ability to an extended version, which would grant me even more armor on activation:

[image: Screenshot of ability in question]

My question is if that additional armor would be reduced by the softcap and if you hit this said softcap that easy on max level too.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. All effects should be affected by soft caps (unless stated otherwise; so it's less effective since you're already at the cap).

I think this variant is a lot more interesting if you're not relying on heavy armor (i.e. if you're wearing a possible mix or maybe even only light/medium armor).

Comment: Do you know if you have hit the softcap on V1 too if you have 7 pcs of Heavy Armor?

Comment: No idea, I'm wearing a full set of medium armor on a Nightblade. :)

Comment: If the armor is traited to give armor you can cap it pretty easily. At veteran ranks I mean

Comment: @Assylum With heavy armor absolutly yes.